# Gradle implementation / api does not get sub-dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to use the new gradle commands in my lib project, but something is wrong.
My lib project, which is upload to bintray to be used in other app afterwards has several sub-dependencies ( gson and commons-codec for instance). Whith the old gradle (before implementation / api), those sub-dependencies where correctly seen and downloaded when integrating the lib in apps.
The command `gradlew :app:dependencies` gave the result

```
[...]
+--- com.test:my_lib:2.4.0.4
|    +--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.6
|    +--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0
[...]
```

However, when I am using `implementation` or `api`, the sub-dependencies seems to be ignored, causing problems in the apps if I do not manually add all the necessary libs.
I do not want to do that since this libs will also be used outside of my company, and we do no want it to be hard to implement.

Using the command `compile` still works, so I am doing that in the meantime, however I do not want to keep using outdated functions since it might cause problems later on.

--EDIT :
I had a look in the download libs with the Project view in Android Studio, and all the sub dependencies are there. They are donwloaded but gradle do not link them to my lib.

Comment: I think that the problem is exporter not api/implementation ... check generated pom file in both cases (old compile and new api/implementation) ... AFAIK jar/aar doesn't contains information about dependencies at all

Comment: I just checked. There is no <dependencies> tag when using implementation / api, but it is there with compile.

Comment: Have you checked it in a new project: does your library work if you don't add inner dependencies explicitly?

Comment: I checked, the lib does not work if I do not add them manually. That's how I detected the problem in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Use this one

`gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies --configuration debugAndroidTestCompileClasspath`

Comment: Sorry for previous comment, add mistyped 'gra' in the lib name somewhere along the line. When re-running your command with correct name, nothing was different. Still no errors apparent.

Comment: Why do you suggest to check configuration bound to instrumented tests? Do you know that this command won't work in case if there is at least one flavor?